# Update model and invoke method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm updating my model object and want a method to be invoked when doing this.

I could potentially

- `findOne`
- change my properties
- invoke the method on the object
- `save`

Is there however a way how I could also achieve this with `update` or `findOneAndUpdate`?

I know that I could potentially also use a pre update event hook, but I didn't find a possibility there to track what fields have changed as I don't want to trigger the method at any update but if a particular field changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to something like mongoose [middlewares](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) or hooks.
You can choose between the following hooks:

- pre: is invoked before the function is executed
- post: is invoked after the function is executed
- you register the hooks in your mongoose-model-schema

Here is a pre-hook example:

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const err = new Error('something went wrong');
  // If you call `next()` with an argument, that argument is assumed to be
  // an error.
  next(err);
});

schema.pre('save', function() {
  // You can also return a promise that rejects
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject(new Error('something went wrong'));
  });
});

schema.pre('save', function() {
  // You can also throw a synchronous error
  throw new Error('something went wrong');
});

schema.pre('save', async function() {
  await Promise.resolve();
  // You can also throw an error in an `async` function
  throw new Error('something went wrong');
});

// later...

// Changes will not be persisted to MongoDB because a pre hook errored out
myDoc.save(function(err) {
  console.log(err.message); // something went wrong
});
```

Comment: I think for my case I rather want a pre update hook. My question though is if I can find out which fields are being updated in the hook as I don't want to trigger my method for every field change but a specific one.

Comment: ahh hmnn i would be surprised if it is possible. Hooks has schema-wide scope (imho)

Comment: @phoebus have you already found an solution? have you consider to write custom setter-methods or to use [virtual-types](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/virtualtype.html)